# ReferenceError: Can't find variable: d3 in new rails6 application with webpacker

Tags: ruby-on-rails, d3.js, webpacker

I am working on a personal project with rails 6 and d3js. In fact trying to prepare configuration to start :-)

I used `yarn add d3js@4.13.0 -T` to install d3js and appended line

```
import * as d3 from "d3";
```

to my `javascript/packs/application.js`

My problem is I am not able to access d3 in the console. Webpacker is not in my comfort zone yet!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Webpack does not export anything to the global scope by default. Anything you import within your Webpack bundles is within the local scope of the module represented by the file you’re working in.

To make a variable available to the global scope, you have to expose it somehow. You could configure something like `expose-loader` to do this. You can instead assign the variable to the global scope, i.e., window, after importing it:

```
// app/javascript/packs/application.js
import * as d3 from "d3"
window.d3 = d3
```

Comment: Thanks for your input! I have tried to run `window.d3 = d3` inside console, but I get same error, should I put this after `import` statement?

Comment: No, you need to tell Webpack to add the imported d3 variable to window by putting that code in a file that Webpack bundles such as `app/javascript/packs/application.js`. Here's a demo: https://github.com/rossta/rails6-webpacker-demo/compare/example/d3

Comment: Got it. However, I have doubts if adding d3js to global scope is the best way. For instance, I want to use d3-selection in a js response template. How should I get access to the d3-selection module?

Comment: You probably wouldn't want to rely on js response templates in a Webpack-driven application where you'd likely push this business logic all the way in to your bundled JS. Otherwise, yes, you'd have to export code to the global scope to continue to use js templates.